# Kohonen SOM plot is displaying observations within cluster plot. how to remove?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, self-organizing-maps

I am running :

```
kmeansDat.t <- som_model$codes[[1]] %>% as.matrix


som_cluster <- cutree(hclust(dist(kmeansDat.t)), 5) %>% as.matrix
# plot these results:
plot(som_model, type="mapping", bgcol = pretty_palette[som_cluster], main = "Clusters") 
add.cluster.boundaries(som_model, som_cluster)
```

My output is cluttered by dark circles each appears to be representing the number of observations in each node. How can I remove them ?

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `pchs=""` inside `plot.kohonen` solves the problem:

```
library(kohonen)
library(magrittr)
# A dataset for testing the code
data(yeast)
X <- matrix(rnorm(100000), nrow=1000)
som_model <- som(X, somgrid(30, 30, "hexagonal"))
kmeansDat.t <- som_model$codes[[1]] %>% as.matrix
pretty_palette <- rainbow(5)   
som_cluster <- cutree(hclust(dist(kmeansDat.t)), 5) %>% as.matrix
# Plot Kohonen's map
plot(som_model, type="mapping", bgcol = pretty_palette[som_cluster], 
     main = "Clusters", pchs="") 
add.cluster.boundaries(som_model, som_cluster)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Marco, appreciate the help. My X matrix has IDs as row-names. Do you know if  there is a straight forward way of tracing back my row-names to the cluster in som_cluster?